# How to send more than 100 images to webserver from android?

Tags: android, image, http-post, android-image

I have to send more than 100 images to webserver from android application.
Currently using [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) library to send image files.

The error that occured to me are:

**1. Socket timeout Error

2. OutofMemory Error**

I even call myClient.setTimeout(time), but its not working.

I am looking for better option to send large number of images to server.
In success of sending each images to server, I am taking response from server like **status: true/false**.

And another question, Should I maintain queue for sending these large number of images and back taking response message from server ?

Sugestions ??

Comment: First of all, there are 131 open issues of Android Async Http Client. I can't understand if android is providing you facility of AndroidHTTP request, why you are not using it? You can also make a queue of all the request and AsyncTask provide such. You should go for basic approach my friend.

Comment: Now you sending 100 images at one time or one by one?

Comment: I have a similar project which sends these images but in a queue. One by  One.

Comment: @NAYOSO I am sending images one by one.

Comment: @MDMalik Can you further describe me how you implemented sending images in queue ? (algorithm or code or any library that you approach)

Comment: @captaindroid sorry for the late response. But in mine is with a progress bar avg of 2.5 sec / image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I've done previously, I'm using XMPP to transfer images to the webserver. From android, you can use [asmack](https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack) to send/receive image files. And from the server side, you need to have XMPP server which for my case, I'm using [prosody](http://prosody.im/) server because I want it to be as light as possible. Then you can create simple program in the webserver to login to that xmpp server. To use it, you can just send from android xmpp to user that you use to login in a program in webserver.